# Is it possible to read and remove messages from the error-queue in MassTransit

Tags: asp.net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

We are using .Net Core/RabbitMQ/MassTransit and I have a Consumer[OrderCreatedEvent] that works well.

I want to have a error recovery mechanism, where I, on startup of the application, would like to read and then remove messages from my error queue.

Is it possible to read and then remove messages from the error-queue in MassTransit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a receive endpoint on the error queue, which would read messages the same as any other receive endpoint. You'd need a consumer that can read the message format and do something with that error message (and likely something different than what was done originally).

*NOTE that any errors on that receive endpoint will be moved to `input-queue_error_error`, and so on, and so on...*

Another option is to set up a shovel on the RabbitMQ server to move messages, but be careful not to move them forever as there may be a legitimate reason the messages were moved to the error queue. But if it was related to a resource outage and it makes sense to just reprocess those messages again, use a shovel to move them back into the main queue.

Comment: I think I got you right if you wanted me to use rabbitmq client lib to read from the queue instead of setting up a consumer with MT. (like this, https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html#basic-get), that is what Im doing now. Thanks for your help